# Is there a way to define a range of numbersl as a constant in C?

Tags: c, char, constants

I'm holding data as an unsigned char and using the upper half as the condition for a negative number.  Is there a way to define a constant NEGATIVE that holds values 128 to 255, for example?

So, if (x == NEGATIVE) when x is between 128 and 255 instead of simply using (x > NEGATIVE) and assigning NEGATIVE to 127

Thanks.

Comment: Why not define NEGATIVE to be 127?

Comment: usually, you `define` a `NEGATIVE` with `#define NEGATIVE 127` and use as shown in above code.

Comment: The lower portions are being used as positive.  The application has positive values that don't generally grow larger than 40 and negative numbers about the same size (roll back to 215 for example).

Comment: == is equal sign. if it bother you to write range  x>=min && x=<max everytime,you can write simple macros.

Comment: user3125367's answer addresses your question. You want to use a char (8 bits) to signify negative when value is over 127 (128 to 255). In 8 bits the commonality between the numbers in the range 128 to 255 is the 1st bit being 1. This 1st bit is 0 for values in the range 0 - 127. You definitely can mask the bit as stated by user3125367 in his 2nd example.

Comment: What's wrong with defining a function  `static inline  bool is_negative(unsigned char x) { ... } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a range and test it for equality. Depending on interpretation of your data, there are various ways to go:

```
#define isNegative(x) ((x) >= 128)
#define isNegative(x) (((x) & 0x80) != 0)
#define isNegative(x) ((signed char)(x) < 0)
```

Comment: @Mark - user3125367's answer addresses your question. You want to use a char (8 bits) to signify negative when value is over 127 (128 to 255). In 8 bits the commonality between the numbers in the range 128 to 255 is the 1st bit being 1. This 1st bit is 0 for values in the range 0 - 127. You definitely can mask the bit as stated by user3125367 in his 2nd example.